# How can I create a variable with data readed with tkinter? Tkinter openfile and create variables of the data

Tags: python-3.x, variables, tkinter, import

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile 
root = Tk() 
root.geometry('200x100') 


def open_file(): 
    file = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('Measurement Files', '*.dat')]) 
    if file is not None: 
        content = file.read() 
        print(content) 

btn = Button(root, text ='Open', command = lambda:open_file()) 
btn.pack(side = TOP, pady = 10) 

mainloop()
```

Python version 3.7 
The code is returning me the content of the file, but how can I do to save each column of the data into different variables?

The data file structure is shown in the pic:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXeEO.png)

And I want to create 5 list with the data of each column.

Comment: You should give us the structure of the datafile, or better show some sample datafile. You talk about "column of data", so maybe it is some CSV dialect?

Comment: The datafile is in .dat extension and it's composed by 5 columns of data (without header):

Comment: 700.00000       0.09300 1.05161 320.52990       31.43325
701.00000       0.09277 1.04902 319.74106       31.35589
702.00000       0.09163 1.03608 315.79689       30.96910
703.00000       0.09293 1.05074 320.26695       31.40746
704.00000       0.09583 1.08353 330.25886       32.38733

Comment: Is there a newline character after the fifth column for each line?  (This doesn't show in your example, but it may have been removed when posting the comment)

Comment: I add a pic about the data structure, from each column i need to create a list of the data.

Comment: OK, I posted an answer that should work with your datafile format

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution where the datafile is parsed into a list of five lists, where each inner list contains one column of data:

```
content = file.read()
cols = [[], [], [], [], []]
for line in content.split('\n'): # loop over all data lines
  for n, col in enumerate(line.split()) # split each line into five columns and loop over
    cols[n].append(float(col)) # convert each data to float and append to corresponding column
```

**EDIT (after your comment):**

If you really need 5 different variables to store your 5 columns, you may simply add the following line after my previous code:

```
a, b, c, d, e = cols
```

Comment: Thank you! But here we are splitting in colums but they are not attributed to any variable right? How can I save the splitted data in different variables?

Comment: It's adding them to a single multi dimensional `cols` array. To access the first column you would use `cols[0]`. The first item  in the first column would be `cols[0][0]` followed by `cols[0][1]` and so on.